# capture several images in one canvas - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, capture

I'm trying to capture several images and save into my django database , but i dont know how to catpture multiple images . i want dynamically add new canvas for new capturing image

this is my html and js to capture images

```js
const player = document.getElementById('player');

const docs = document.getElementById('document')


const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
 
const constraints = {
  video: true,
};
  
captureButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  const imgFormat = canvas.toDataURL();
  docs.value = imgFormat 
  e.preventDefault();
 
});
  
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then((stream) => {
    player.srcObject = stream;
  });  

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
                <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" dir="ltr">{% csrf_token %}

                    <input type="text" name="documents" id="document">
                    <video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
                    <button id="capture">Capture</button>
                    <canvas id="canvas" width=320 height=240></canvas>
                   

                    <button class="header pt-2  text-white px-4 p-1 rounded-lg mt-4">{% trans "save" %}</button>
                </form>
```

im not sure if it is possible or not ? please if you know something in this case let me know , i appreciate your helps ..

Comment: I'm not sure what "capture several images" means exactly. Can you clarify?

Comment: @ggorlen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69415265/how-to-add-multiple-values-to-an-input-tag-js can you check it out please

Comment: Please edit this question instead of asking new ones.

Comment: @ggorlen i will , but please could take a look at that question

Comment: I did, but I still don't really understand what you're asking or what you're trying to achieve, exactly. Maybe take a step back and try to phrase the problem in agile story format: "when the user clicks an image, it should make a request to the backend and store it in the database" or something understandable that communicates the desired behavior and detailed workflow you're trying to implement, what exactly is going wrong and where, etc. Are you trying to capture images from a video stream?